# Zen-cart website too much parse and query time on a page

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, zen-cart

We just moved our site to godaddy hosting and the our zencart site http://www.boostpromotions.com/zen_new/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=63 takes a considerable amount of time loading the product pages.

Parse Time: 18.164 - Number of Queries: 7726 - Query Time: 17.2115788776

Why is there 7000+ queries? the page loads in minutes and we fear we might lose so many customers because of the page load time.

any recommendations or plugins for this?

Comment: Welcome. This question is not programming-related, and could be removed. You may try [Super User](http://superuser.com) which is computer-related, but not programming-related. See [ask].

Comment: we solved this issue by switching to bluehost. before we moved to godaddy, we are not experiencing issues (hostgator). we moved because it's cheap, but found out later on it's not optimized to support full fledged e-commerce sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen sometimes 30-40k queries on this.

Typically this is caused by a developer making several queries for every product. I have seen several coders fetch the products_name for example when it can be in the initial DB query call.

1. Optimize your product listing your calls for your product bu using join statements.
2. Enable SQL caching in your includes/configure.php
3. Set the caching time in your $db->Execute() calls
4. Consider using a disk caching method like: https://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1777